# Lottery Distributions Question

Tags: probability-distributions

In a certain lottery, $7$ balls are drawn at random (without replacement) from $n$ balls numbered $1$ through $n$.

Let $P$ be the probability that no pair of consecutive numbers is drawn. Let $Q$ be the probability that exactly one pair of consecutive numbers is drawn.

If $P=Q$, and both $P$ and $Q$ are positive, then determine $n$ with proof.

---

I'm not sure where to start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can start by computing  the number of ways to place $k$ balls into $n$ slots such that no two consecutive slots are filled (this will be $n!$ times the probability that no two consecutive numbers are drawn). Call this $N_p(n,k)$.

To do that, note that either the last slot on the right is filled or not.
In either case, group each of the balls (except possibly the ball going into the last slot) with a dummy ball to its right; you can do this because every ball must have an empty slot to its right.  Consider the two cases separately.

If there is no ball in the last slot, then you have $k$ clumps to place but your clumping has "cost" you $k$ slots, so there are $\binom{n-k}{k}$ ways to do this.  If there is a ball in the last slot, then you have $k-1$ clumps to place among only $n-1$ slots and your clumping has "cost" you just $k-1$ slots, so there are $\binom{n-k}{k-1}$ ways to do this. Combining, we get
$$
N_p(n,k)=\binom{n-k}{k}+\binom{n-k}{k-1} = \binom{n-k+1}{k}
$$

Now let's 
compute  the number of ways to place $k$ balls into $n$ slots such that exactly one set of two consecutive slots are filled (this will be $n!$ times the probability that exactly one pair of consecutive numbers are drawn). Call this $N_q(n,k)$.

To do that, glue two balls together and treat that blob as one ball; at the end, we will have to decide which one of the $k-1$ balls is the double ball and that will multiply our counting by a factor of $k-1$.
We again note that either the last slot on the right is filled or not.
In either case, group each of the balls (except possibly the ball going into the last slot) with a dummy ball to its right.

If there is no ball in the last slot, then you have $k-1$ clumps to place but your clumping has "cost" you $k-1$ slots and your ball doubling has cost you one slot, so there are effectively $n-k$ slots and there are  $\binom{n-k}{k-1}$ ways to do this.  If there is a ball in the last slot (whether or not it is the double ball), then you have $k-2$ clumps to place among only $n-1$ slots and your clumping has "cost" you just $k-2$ slots, so there are $\binom{n-k}{k-2}$ ways to do this. Combining, we get
$$
N_q(n,k)=(k-1) \binom{n-k}{k-1}+\binom{n-k}{k-2} = (k-1) \binom{n-k+1}{k-1}
$$
Try it out for $n=7, k=3$ where it is easy enough to list the $20$ arrangements having exactly one touching pair:  $(3-1) \binom{5}{2} = 20$.

Lastly, specialize to $k=7$ and we have to find some $n$ such that 
$N_q(n,k) = N_p(n,k)$.
$$
\binom{n-6}{7} = 6 \binom{6}{6} \\
\frac{(n-6)(n-7)\cdots(n-11)(n-12)}{7!} = 6 \frac{(n-6)(n-7)\cdots(n-11)}{6!} \\
\frac{n-12}{7} = 6 \\
n=54
$$